# Gremlin .repeat() max depth

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I have a dataset that contains a few hundred paths that represent a series of recorded events. I want to find out how long the average event path is. It's stored in a quite simple graph with about 50k nodes on Azure Cosmos Graph DB.

I have a gremlin query that looks like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('user').out('has_event').repeat(out('next').simplePath()).until(out().count().is(0))
```

Traverse all events until the end of the events chain.

However, I'm getting the following error: `Gremlin Query Execution Error: Exceeded maximum number of loops on a repeat() step. Cannot exceed 32 loops.` I wasn't aware of the 32 loops limit, the idea I had for my analysis will exceed paths of 32 step length many times.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do or does cosmos DB really 'stop' after 32 loops? How about other graph dbs like Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [limit of CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-limits). I'm not aware of other TinkerPop implementations that have this limit, so choosing another graph database would likely solve your problem. I suspect that the limit is in place to prevent a runaway fan-out of a query as the structure of your graph will greatly affect performance.